# Servo/Ipc_channel trivial example doesn't work

Tags: rust, error-handling, concurrency, ipc, servo

I'm attempting to get the [ipc-channel](https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel) package to work and I can't get a trivial example to run.

I have a rust cargo called process_handler that creates an `IpcOneShotServer` and then spawns a server. (NOTE: most of the code comes from the examples as shown in the test.rs file linked in the repo).

```
use std::process::Command;
use ipc_channel::ipc::{self, IpcOneShotServer, IpcSender, IpcReceiver};

fn main() {
    
    let datavec = vec![("Peter".to_string(), "36".to_string())];
    
    let guiserver = spawn_server(
                  "/Users/peterweyand/Code/rustprojects/project1.1/project1_1/process_handler/src/rungui.sh".to_string(), 
                  // &server_args
                  &server_name0
              );
}

pub fn spawn_server(address:String, test_name: &str) -> std::process::Child {
    Command::new(address) 
        .arg(test_name)
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to execute server process")
}
```

Which calls the following bash file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "inside rungui.sh"
echo "First Parameter of the script is $1"

cd /Users/peterweyand/Code/rustprojects/project1.1/project1_1
cargo build && cargo run -- $1
```

Which calls my crate that I want to access the `IpcSender` on:

```
use iced::widget::{button, container, row, column, text, text_input};
use iced::{executor, Application, Command, Length, Settings};
use ipc_channel::ipc::{self, IpcOneShotServer, IpcSender, IpcReceiver};
use iced::Color;
// use iced::widget::column;
use self::theme::Theme;
use self::widget::Element;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::process::Command as ProcessCommand;
use std::env;
use std::io;
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    println!("&cloned_string: {:?}", args[1].clone());
    let tx2 = IpcSender::<Vec<(String, String)>>::connect(args[1].clone()).unwrap();     
}
```

Which produces the following result -

```
&cloned_string: "org.rust-lang.ipc-channel.8687042407079962014"
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: Unknown(1102) }', src/main.rs:59:76
```

According to [the official rust error index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/error-index.html) there is no error code 1102.

So, why is this failing? I would expect that since the latter cargo is a child process it should be able to access the IpcSender. This isn't fancy at all, just accessing the messages between processes. I'm not wrapping one channel or server in another or anything like that.

I've also asked the question in [their github issues](https://github.com/servo/ipc-channel/issues/305)

Here is a link to [my repo](https://github.com/patientplatypus6/icedrustplay). `cd` into the process handler folder and `cargo run`.

(EDIT: The most trivial example I can make is [here](https://github.com/patientplatypus6/servoproblemexample). There are no extraneous dependencies or commented out code. Just run `sudo cargo build && sudo cargo run`. It outputs the same error as the other repo.)

I have as trivial an example as I can make and it doesn't appear to work. It may be something stupid, but I thought I'd put it here in case someone comes along and is debugging their code.

Comment: That error code is from the crate, not from Rust. Even if it did exist in the Rust errors it would probably not be about the error you're facing at all. And as it's wrapped in `Unknown` it might even be from one of it's dependencies. If it is an error code at all.

Comment: Hmmm...possibly? When you say the error "is from the crate" then I take what you're saying as "there is an error from the code you are running, not in the build environment, but it could be in one of the dependencies." OK. So then why is there an error code at all if it can't be looked up? If there's an error code it should be written down what that error is somewhere presumably.